# trim in includegraphics only stretches the image

Tags: floats

I am using following code to crop left and right part of a certain image and including it.

```
\documentclass[aip,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\draft % marks overfull lines with a black rule on the right

\usepackage{graphicx, float}

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\fbox{\includegraphics[width = 0.95\columnwidth,trim = 2cm 0 2cm 0,clip]{patterndeath}}
\caption{\label{patterndeath}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Somehow, instead of trimming the left and right part of the figure, it simply stretches the image vertically. Is what am I doing right?

The original graph looks like this:
[image: Trim1]

After usig trim option as given in the above code it looks like this one:
[image: Trim2]

Thus, the left and right blank margins are still there, only image is stretched vertically.

Thank you

**Update** : I solved the problem now. Actually I was creating a .dvi file using the command
    latex file.tex 
In the dvi file so generated, the image is indeed stretched. But once I convert this file to pdf, everything is fine and trim works as expected.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The trim is not applied to your width but to the original image. It this was a square it is now an portrait rectangle, and this is then scaled to get the requested width and so the image gets higher.

Comment: @tohecz: I have now edited my question with MWE. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given MWE uses `\fbox`, but the frame is gone in the posted image. Also neither or `trim` or `width` without `height` distort an image. But, if both `width` and `height` are given, then the image is distorted, unless width and height are given in the correct ratio.

If both `width` and `height` are used/needed, then option `keepaspectratio` ensures that the proportions of the image are kept, e.g.:

```
\includegraphics[
  trim=2cm 0 2cm 0,
  clip,
  width=\linewidth,
  height=\textheight,
  keepaspectratio,
]{patterndeath}
```